# Abstracting out a common idiom

Tags: javascript

In this code

```
if (direction === 'up') {
    for (key in elements) {
        if (elements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            elements[key].style.opacity = statics.elapsed / max_time;
        }
    }
} else if (direction === 'down') {
    for (key in elements) {
        if (elements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            elements[key].style.opacity = (max_time - statics.elapsed) / max_time;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to abstract out this common idiom:

```
for (key in elements) {
    if (elements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // function using elements[key] and outside parameters
    }
}
```

so I could simply write

```
manyElements(element, function () {
});
```

How would I write the function prototype as starting point.  My guess would be.

```
function manyElements (elements, the_function) {
    for (key in elements) {
        if (elements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            the_function();
        }
    }
}
```

but I need access to outside parameters, what is the best way to pass these in?  Is this a good idea in general, to abstract out this code?

It seems like I would have to pass each parameter in individually defeating the purpose of making a general purpose function.

I don't prefer not to use an outside library, except for correlation.  Per answer here is lodash implementation:

**Snippet 1**

```
  function forEach(collection, callback, thisArg) {
    if (callback && typeof thisArg == 'undefined' && isArray(collection)) {
      var index = -1,
          length = collection.length;

      while (++index < length) {
        if (callback(collection[index], index, collection) === false) {
          break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      each(collection, callback, thisArg);
    }
    return collection;
  }
```

**Snippet 2**

```
var each = createIterator(eachIteratorOptions);
```

**Snippet 3**

```
  function createIterator() {
    var data = {
      'arrayLoop': '',
      'bottom': '',
      'hasDontEnumBug': hasDontEnumBug,
      'isKeysFast': isKeysFast,
      'objectLoop': '',
      'nonEnumArgs': nonEnumArgs,
      'noCharByIndex': noCharByIndex,
      'shadowed': shadowed,
      'top': '',
      'useHas': true
    };

    // merge options into a template data object
    for (var object, index = 0; object = arguments[index]; index++) {
      for (var key in object) {
        data[key] = object[key];
      }
    }
    var args = data.args;
    data.firstArg = /^[^,]+/.exec(args)[0];

    // create the function factory
    var factory = Function(
        'createCallback, hasOwnProperty, isArguments, isString, objectTypes, ' +
        'nativeKeys, propertyIsEnumerable',
      'return function(' + args + ') {\n' + iteratorTemplate(data) + '\n}'
    );
    // return the compiled function
    return factory(
      createCallback, hasOwnProperty, isArguments, isString, objectTypes,
      nativeKeys, propertyIsEnumerable
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this several times in your code, there is nothing wrong with abstracting it out. You almost have the answer already too: Just pass the parameters you need back into the function that you passed into `manyElements`. I'd go for passing both the key and the value, since you might need the key in some places (e.g. to change the assignment to something else).

```
function manyElements (elements, the_function) {
    for (key in elements) {
        if (elements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            the_function(key, elements[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage would be like this:

```
if (direction === 'up') {
    manyElements(elements, function (key, value) {
        value.style.opacity = statics.elapsed / max_time;
    });
} else if (direction === 'down') {
    manyElements(elements, function (key, value) {
        value.style.opacity = (max_time - statics.elapsed) / max_time;
    });
}
```

I wouldn't call the function manyElements though, because that name doesn't really explain what the function does. Something like `forEachProperty` might be more self-documenting.

Answer (score 2):

At first, some there are some libraries, like lodash or underscore that already do it. Check the http://lodash.com/docs#forEach function.

Secondly, you can use Object.keys(elements).forEach(function (key) { ... }) to shortcut the code.

And at third, you may need to read about the JavaScript functions - they can be passed to other functions as parameters and then called. Like this:

```
function do(something) {
 ...
 something(item);
 ...
}
do(function (arg) { console.log(arg); });
```

Comment: interesting that Object.keys does not include the prototype chain - what I was looking for, ie9+ unless using work around.